# Infinite Convergent Series - Discovery

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

Does there exist an infinite convergent series *s* for any given irrational number *a* such that the sum of the series *s* is *a*?

In other words: Is every irrational number the sum of an infinite convergent series?

Further: Given an irrational number *a*, is there a way beyond trial and error to find one or more infinite series that converge to *a*?

Comment: What do you think ? Have you found ideas to build such series ?

Comment: How about their decimal expansion? Continued fraction expansion?

Comment: Presumably you want series with rational entries, otherwise the sequence $a_1 = a$ and $a_{n+1} = 0$ satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_j = a$.

Comment: How about $\frac a2+\frac a4+\frac a8+\cdots$?

Comment: @player3236 I think you should post your comment as an example. (The OP is likely to be more familiar with decimal representation than continued fractions.)

Comment: @EthanBolker Agreed. But they said one or more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm compiling the answers in the comments.

If you do not require the numbers in the series to be rational, the series:
$$(a,0,0,0,0,\dots) \quad\text{and} \quad \left(\frac a2, \frac a4, \frac a8,\frac a {16},\dots\right)$$

Have sums converging to $a$.

If instead you require them to be rational, the decimal expansion is a good starting point:

$$(3,0.1,0.04,0.001,0.0005, \dots) \quad\text{and}\quad (4, -0.8, -0.05, -0.008, -0.0004, \dots)$$

can both have sums converging to $\pi$, for example.

For a more interesting example, see [Greedy algorithm for Egyptian fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions):
$$(3, \frac18,\frac1{61},\frac1{5020},\dots)$$

So the answer to your question is affirmative, if the numbers of the series are taken from $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q$. This is the basis for $\overline{\mathbb Q} =\mathbb R$, after all.

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks, the latter example is what I need.